# Left Join with three tables not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with event information (name, date, description, etc.) and a table containing attendance information (person, event, whether they're attending or not). I am trying to create a view from these two tables to show the total number of 'yes' responses and total number of 'no' responses based on an event. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT e.id AS event, COUNT(yea.attendance) AS yes, COUNT(nea.attendance) AS no
FROM event_information e
LEFT JOIN event_attendance yea
ON e.id = yea.event_id AND yea.attendance = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN event_attendance nea
ON e.id = nea.event_id AND nea.attendance = 'N'
GROUP BY event;
```

So I would expect this to return each event ID (1,2,3 and 4) with the corresponding number of 'yes' and 'no' responses.

```
event    yes    no
    1      3     1
    2      2     2
    3      1     3
    4      4     0
```

Instead the following is returned

```
event    yes    no
    1      3     3
    2      4     4
    3      3     3
    4      4     0
```

When I only join the event_attendance table once to retrieve either the yes or no results, then the correct number is brought through. It's only when I re-join the same table that I get incorrect results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT e.id AS event, SUM(a.attendance = 'Y') AS yes, SUM(a.attendance = 'N') AS no
FROM event_information e LEFT JOIN
     event_attendance a
     ON e.id = a.event_id A
GROUP BY event;
```

Your method doesn't work because it generates a Cartesian product for the "yes"es and "no"es for each event.  If there is zero or one in either category, then it should work.  But, if there is more than one for both, you start to get overcounting.

EDIT:

Also, if all events have at least one attendance record, then you don't need the `join`:

```
SELECT a.event_id AS event,
       SUM(a.attendance = 'Y') AS yes, SUM(a.attendance = 'N') AS no
FROM event_attendance a
GROUP BY event_id;
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks. Why does it generate a Cartesian product here?

Comment: @user2696497 That's what join does, it always creates a cartesian product among all the tables being joined.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
SELECT e.id AS event
, SUM(CASE WHEN yea.attendance = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS yes
, SUM(CASE WHEN yea.attendance = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS no
FROM event_information e
LEFT JOIN event_attendance a ON e.id = a.event_id
GROUP BY event;
```